# PHP : converting "horizontal" listed array in array with other structure

Tags: php, arrays, list

I got the following array:

```
Array
(
    [ids] => 21858, 21859
    [names] => John Doe, Mike Clark
)
```

I want to transform it to:

```
Array
(
    [21858] => John Doe
    [21859] => Mike Clark
)
```

I tried this, with no luck

```
foreach($arr_orig as $key => $value) {
   $arr_new[$key['ids']] = explode(',', $key['names']);
}
```

I can't sort this out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ids = explode(",",$array['ids']);
$names= explode(",",$array['names']);
```

Explode both using `,`, create another array to store the results.
   Just added a check on names array.

```
$newArray=[];
for($i=0;$i<count($ids);$i++){
  $name = key_exists($i,$names)?$names[$i]:"";
  $newArray[$ids[$i]]=  $name;
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: Maybe use trim inside the for to clear spaces after commas.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can works for you:

```
$ids = explode(",", $arr['ids']);

$names = explode(",", $arr['names']);


$newarr = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($ids as $key=>$val){
  $newarr[$val] = $names[$i];

$i++;
}

print_r($newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data =
[
    'ids'   => '21858, 21859',
    'names' => 'John Doe, Mike Clark'
];

$result = 
array_combine(
    ...array_values(
        array_map(
            function($v) {
                return explode(', ', $v);
            }, $data
        )
    )
);

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  21858 => 'John Doe',
  21859 => 'Mike Clark',
)
```

Really it's a case of using the exploded ids for keys and names for values with array_combine.